# answer yes automatically on permission removal

Tags: powershell

I want to remove several user from accessing another users calendar. And every time i user the removal command it ask me,

"Are you sure you want to perform this action?"

If i have a CSV and run a for each loop on all the users i want to remove from another user how can i make it answer yes automatically for each user so i don't have to do it manually ?

```
Remove-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "user@contoso.se:\calendar" -user "user@contoso.se"
```

Comment: You may carefully (re-)read the help for [Remove-MailboxFolderPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/remove-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps). The [-Confirm:$false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/remove-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps#parameters) parameter does what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Olaf is gently suggesting, the `-Confirm` switch will ease your pain.

This is a Common Parameter, meaning you can use it for practically all PowerShell cmds.

**How ConfirmPreference Works**

In PowerShell, cmdlet authors specify the impact level of a command on the environment where they should run.

The impact level is either None, Low, Medium or High.

PowerShell defaults to `High`, by the way.

When a command runs, it checks to see if its Impact level is higher than your specified `$ConfirmPreference`.  If the command's impact level is **higher** than your specified Preference, then it stops and prompts you for confirmation.

**What if we don't want to Confirm Everytime**

PowerShell lets us set our own risk tolerance.  We can do this in one of two ways.

- Set our Preference for the current script
- Override for one command only

**Specifying our Impact Tolerance with a Variable**

When you fire up PowerShell, you'll have a value specified in `$ConfirmPReference`, which is one of PowerShell's many automatic variables.  You can change this value to either `None`,`Low`, `Medium` or `High`.

You could specify at the top of your script something like this:

```
$ConfirmPreference = 'MEDIUM'
```

This means that any command which has an impact level of None, Low or Medium will get automatic approval and won't require any input.

**Overriding for one Command**

If you want just one command to run with elevated impact grants, you can append `-Confirm:$false` with its someone wonky syntax.

**If you really want this command** to not confirm before doing things...then you'll want to update your resume, then run the following.

```
Remove-MailboxFolderPermission `
   -Identity "user@contoso.se:\calendar" `
   -user "user@contoso.se"
   -Confirm:$false
```